# Mock multiple fetch calls with state updates in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am having a ReactJS component which does two things:
- on ComponentDidMount it will retrieve a list of entries
- on Button click it will submit the select entry to a backend

The problem is that i need to mock both requests (made with fetch) in order to test it properly. In my current testcase i want to test a failure in the submit on the button click. However due some odd reason the setState is triggered however the update from that is received after i want to compare it.

Dumps i did for the test. First one is the state as listen in the test. The second is from the code itself where it is setting state().error to the error received from the call

```
FAIL  react/src/components/Authentication/DealerSelection.test.jsx (6.689s)
● Console

  console.log react/src/components/Authentication/DealerSelection.test.jsx:114
    { loading: true,
      error: null,
      options: [ { key: 22, value: 22, text: 'Stationstraat 5' } ] }
  console.log react/src/components/Authentication/DealerSelection.jsx:52
    set error to: my error
```

The actual test code:

```
it('throws error message when dealer submit fails', done => {
  const mockComponentDidMount = Promise.resolve(
    new Response(JSON.stringify({"data":[{"key":22,"value":"Stationstraat 5"}],"default":22}), {
      status: 200,
      headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' }
    })
  );
  const mockButtonClickFetchError = Promise.reject(new Error('my error'));

  jest.spyOn(global, 'fetch').mockImplementation(() => mockComponentDidMount);
  const element = mount(<DealerSelection />);

  process.nextTick(() => {
    jest.spyOn(global, 'fetch').mockImplementation(() => mockButtonClickFetchError);
    const button = element.find('button');
    button.simulate('click');
    process.nextTick(() => {
      console.log(element.state()); // state.error null even though it is set with setState but arrives just after this log statement
      global.fetch.mockClear();
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

This is the component that i actually use:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Form, Header, Select, Button, Banner } from '@omnius/react-ui-elements';
import ClientError from '../../Error/ClientError';
import { fetchBackend } from './service';
import 'whatwg-fetch';
import './DealerSelection.scss';

class DealerSelection extends Component {

  state = {
    loading: true,
    error: null,
    dealer: '',
    options: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.title = "Select dealer";

    fetchBackend(
      '/agent/account/dealerlist',
      {},
      this.onDealerListSuccessHandler,
      this.onFetchErrorHandler
    );
  }

  onDealerListSuccessHandler = json => {
    const options = json.data.map((item) => {
      return {
        key: item.key,
        value: item.key,
        text: item.value
      };
    });
    this.setState({
      loading: false,
      options,
      dealer: json.default
    });
  }

  onFetchErrorHandler = err => {
    if (err instanceof ClientError) {
      err.response.json().then(data => {
        this.setState({
          error: data.error,
          loading: false
        });
      });
    } else {
      console.log('set error to', err.message);
      this.setState({
        error: err.message,
        loading: false
      });
    }
  }

  onSubmitHandler = () => {
    const { dealer } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      loading: true,
      error: null
    });

    fetchBackend(
      '/agent/account/dealerPost',
      {
        dealer
      },
      this.onDealerSelectSuccessHandler,
      this.onFetchErrorHandler
    );
  }

  onDealerSelectSuccessHandler = json => {
    if (!json.error) {
      window.location = json.redirect; // Refresh to return back to MVC
    }
    this.setState({
      error: json.error
    });
  }

  onChangeHandler = (event, key) => {
    this.setState({
      dealer: event.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { loading, error, dealer, options } = this.state;
    const errorBanner = error ? <Banner type='error' text={error} /> : null;

    return (
      <div className='dealerselection'>
        <Form>
          <Header as="h1">Dealer selection</Header>
          { errorBanner }
          <Select
            label='My dealer'
            fluid
            defaultValue={dealer}
            onChange={this.onChangeHandler}
            maxHeight={5}
            options={options}
          />
          <Button
            primary
            fluid
            onClick={this.onSubmitHandler}
            loading={loading}
          >Select dealer</Button>
        </Form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DealerSelection;
```

Comment: how about mocking the function that contains `setState` and will be called after `click` event. Then checking the arguments fed to that function are what you want.(e.g. by using `toHaveBeenCalledWith`)

Comment: @HankChiu could do that to test the binding on the button but that does not test the way how the method is handling the response it receives. So how the mapping is between the response error or 200 response body itself towards setState for example

Comment: Can you share the code for your click handler?

Comment: @brian-lives-outdoors i added the full component itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting, this one took a little while to chase down.

---

Relevant parts from the Node.js doc on [Event Loop, Timers, and `process.nextTick()`](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/):

> `process.nextTick()` is not technically part of the event loop. Instead, the `nextTickQueue` will be processed after the current operation is completed, regardless of the current phase of the event loop.
>
> ...any time you call `process.nextTick()` in a given phase, all callbacks passed to `process.nextTick()` will be resolved before the event loop continues.

In other words, Node starts processing the `nextTickQueue` once the current operation is completed, and it will continue *until the queue is empty* before continuing with the event loop.

This means that if `process.nextTick()` is called while the `nextTickQueue` is processing, *the callback is added to the queue and it will be processed before the event loop continues*.

The doc warns:

> This can create some bad situations because **it allows you to "starve" your I/O by making recursive `process.nextTick()` calls**, which prevents the event loop from reaching the **poll** phase.

...and as it turns out you can starve your `Promise` callbacks as well:

```
test('Promise and process.nextTick order', done => {
  const order = [];
  
  Promise.resolve().then(() => { order.push('2') });
  
  process.nextTick(() => {
    Promise.resolve().then(() => { order.push('7') });
    order.push('3');  // this runs while processing the nextTickQueue...
    process.nextTick(() => {
      order.push('4');  // ...so all of these...
      process.nextTick(() => {
        order.push('5');  // ...get processed...
        process.nextTick(() => {
          order.push('6');  // ...before the event loop continues...
        });
      });
    });
  });

  order.push('1');

  setTimeout(() => {
    expect(order).toEqual(['1','2','3','4','5','6','7']);  // ...and 7 gets added last
    done();
  }, 0);
});
```

So in this case the nested `process.nextTick()` callback that logs `element.state()` ends up running **before** the `Promise` callbacks that would set `state.error` to `'my error'`.

---

It is because of this that the doc recommends the following:

> *We recommend developers use `setImmediate()` in all cases because it's easier to reason about*

---

If you change your `process.nextTick` calls to `setImmediate` (and create your `fetch` mocks as *functions* so `Promise.reject()` doesn't run immediately and cause an error) then your test should work as expected:

```
it('throws error message when dealer submit fails', done => {
  const mockComponentDidMount = () => Promise.resolve(
    new Response(JSON.stringify({"data":[{"key":22,"value":"Stationstraat 5"}],"default":22}), {
      status: 200,
      headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' }
    })
  );
  const mockButtonClickFetchError = () => Promise.reject(new Error('my error'));

  jest.spyOn(global, 'fetch').mockImplementation(mockComponentDidMount);
  const element = mount(<DealerSelection />);

  setImmediate(() => {
    jest.spyOn(global, 'fetch').mockImplementation(mockButtonClickFetchError);
    const button = element.find('button');
    button.simulate('click');
    setImmediate(() => {
      console.log(element.state()); // state.error is 'my error'
      global.fetch.mockClear();
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation! I could of course also mock more generic functions to ensure that maybe lets ticks can be skipped but from the other hand the component is also handling it like this! Great

Answer (score 0):

There are several asynchronous calls required to update the state, so your `process.nextTick()` isn't sufficient. To update the state, this needs to happen:

- your test code clicks, and the event handler callback is queued
- the event handler callback runs, runs `fetch`, gets a promise rejection, and runs the error handler
- the error handler runs `setState`, which queues the state update (`setState` is asynchronous!)
- your test code runs, checking the element's state
- the state update runs

In short, you need to wait longer before asserting on the state.

A useful idiom to "wait" without nested `process.nextTick()` calls is to define a test helper

```
function wait() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve));
}
```

and then do

```
await wait();
```

as many times as required in your test code. Note that this requires you to define test functions as

```
test(async () => {

})
```

rather than

```
test(done => {

})
```